# How to detect that new app has been installed on the device?

Tags: android

How does CleanMaster app detect that a new app has been installed on the device? Whenever I install a new app, I get a popup asking if I want to move the app to SD card.

I am trying to code similar behaviour but cannot find a way to do it.

Comment: You need to write a receiver for that..

Comment: @kalyanpvs Any more info or keyword which I can search in Google docs?

Comment: @ok..i will post complete answer..

Comment: posted my answer check like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the [ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) Broadcast Intent, but the application being installed doesn't receive this.

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

Android provides `String android.content.Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED ="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED"` Broadcast Action: A new application package has been installed on the device. The data contains the name of the package. Note that the newly installed package does not receive this broadcast.

You can write a `BroadcastReceiver` receiving the `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED` for that.

Answer (score 1):

For this You need to write a receiver class like this

```
public class AppInstallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Perform Your opeartion

        }

    }
```

And register it in manifest like.

```
  <receiver android:name="com.example.AppInstallReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_INSTALL" />

        <data android:scheme="package" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: `Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL` was deprecated in API level 14.

Comment: @AduaitPokhriyal yes you are right but i am not only using that Using another action also..based upon the action it will be fire..